# Open function in CLIPS does not work when CLIPS is integrated with .NET

Tags: clips

Tried using this open in c#;
`"(open " + "CarFluidTest.test.txt" + " " + "b" +" "+ "w" + ")"`
inside an Eval  but I get this error:

`[ARGACCES5] Function open expected argument #3 to be of type string`

yet in the open function string w is the third argument.

Help fix this.

Answer (score 0):

The command you're passing to eval is

```
(open CarFluidTest.test.txt b  w)
```

Symbols (without quotes) and strings (with quotes) are two different types in CLIPS. You should be passing "w" as the third argument, not w. To do this, modify your constructed string to

```
"(open " + "CarFluidTest.test.txt" + " " + "b" +" "+ "\"w\"" + ")"
```

Comment: the test.txt is file that I added to the solution CarFluidtest as an embedded resource when I do the printout with the logical name b still nothing is written on test.txt where am I wrong?

Comment: Embedded resources are read-only; you can't write to them. In addition, they're not just some file sitting out there in the file system; they're embedded in the executable. So you can't use the CLIPS open function to read content from them either.